# flutter calendar carousel show events according to the month

Tags: flutter, calendar

I'm trying to build a calendar app using the flutter calendar carousel. What I  need to do is I want to show the events assigned to the month when the user swipes through the months.

```
checkCurrentMonth() {
    selectedMonth = DateTime.parse(_targetDateTime.toString()).month.toInt();
    selectedYear = DateTime.parse(_targetDateTime.toString()).year.toInt();

    _markedDateMap.events.forEach((key, value) {
      // print(_markedDateMap.events);

      print(DateTime.parse(key.toString()).month.toInt());
      if (selectedMonth == DateTime.parse(key.toString()).month.toInt() &&
          selectedYear == DateTime.parse(key.toString()).year.toInt()) {
        // print(_markedDateMap.events[key]);
        _selectedHolidays.add(_markedDateMap.events[key]);
      }
    });

    // for (var item in _selectedHolidays) {
    //   print("000000000000000 $item");
    //   gatheredEvents.add(GatherEvents.fromJson(item));
    // }
    print(_selectedHolidays[0].getTitle());
    print(_markedDateMap.events.length);
  }
```

I'm getting the following error.

```
Class 'List<Event>' has no instance getter 'getTitle'.
Receiver: Instance(length:1) of '_GrowableList'
Tried calling: getTitle
```

here's my _markedDateMap

```
EventList<Event> _markedDateMap = new EventList<Event>(
    events: {
      new DateTime(2020, 12, 29): [
        new Event(
          date: new DateTime(2020, 12, 29),
          title: 'Poya Day',
          icon: _poyaeventIcon(DateTime(2020, 12, 29).day.toString()),
          dot: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1.0),
            color: Colors.red,
            height: 5.0,
            width: 5.0,
          ),
        ),
      ],
      new DateTime(2021, 01, 14): [
        new Event(
          date: new DateTime(2021, 01, 14),
          title: 'Tamil Thai Pongal Day',
          icon: _otheralleventIcon(DateTime(2021, 01, 14).day.toString()),
          dot: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1.0),
            color: Colors.red,
            height: 5.0,
            width: 5.0,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    },
  );
```

please help me with this.

Comment: Where is your `_markerdDateMap` declaration ?

Comment: Hi @dm_tr I edited my question

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart native built-in methods, you cannot call other methods on `List`. You are actually calling the method `getTitle` on a list of `Event`. If you want to see the title of all Events of your List, you must either use a loop or get a particular index.

```
for (var event in _selectedHolidays[0]) print(event.getTitle());

// or

print(_selectedHolidays[0].first.getTitle());
```